# Replacing string with empty vector

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop

I'm trying to modify this code so that if the input of this function contains the letter 'Z', it will return return an empty vector. I am able to do this for the letter 'Q'  or 'Z' if it is at the beginning of string, but unfortunately it won't work if either of these two letters are at the end.

```
function d = change(a)
new_claim = regexprep(a, 'A', '2');
new_claim1 = regexprep(new_claim, 'B', '2');
new_claim2 = regexprep(new_claim1, 'C', '2');
new_claim3 = regexprep(new_claim2, 'D', '3');
new_claim4 = regexprep(new_claim3, 'E', '3');
new_claim5 = regexprep(new_claim4, 'F', '3');
new_claim6 = regexprep(new_claim5, 'G', '4');
new_claim7 = regexprep(new_claim6, 'H', '4');
new_claim8 = regexprep(new_claim7, 'I', '4');
new_claim9 = regexprep(new_claim8, 'J', '5');
new_claim10 = regexprep(new_claim9, 'K', '5');
new_claim11 = regexprep(new_claim10, 'L', '5');
new_claim12 = regexprep(new_claim11, 'M', '6');
new_claim13 = regexprep(new_claim12, 'N', '6');
new_claim14 = regexprep(new_claim13, 'O', '6');
new_claim15 = regexprep(new_claim14, 'P', '7');
new_claim16 = regexprep(new_claim15, 'R', '7');
new_claim17 = regexprep(new_claim16, 'S', '7');
new_claim18 = regexprep(new_claim17, 'T', '8');
new_claim19 = regexprep(new_claim18, 'U', '8');
new_claim20 = regexprep(new_claim19, 'V', '8');
new_claim21 = regexprep(new_claim20, 'W', '9');
new_claim22 = regexprep(new_claim21, 'X', '9');
new_claim23 = regexprep(new_claim22, 'Y', '9');
new_claim24 = regexprep(new_claim23, '-', ' ');
new_claim25 = regexprep(new_claim24, '(', '');
new_claim26 = regexprep(new_claim25, ')','');
d = new_claim26;
if strfind(d,'Q') == true 
    d = [];
elseif strfind(d,'Z') == true 
    d = [];
else
    return;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's your desire to check to see if a string contains the letter `Z` or `z`, maybe put this at the beginning of your code:

```
if ~isempty(regexp(a, '[Zz]'))
    d = [];
    return;
end
```

If you also wanted to check for `Q` or `q`, you can do:

```
if ~isempty(regexp(a, '[ZzQq]'))
    d = [];
    return;
end
```

The above uses a regular expression to see if there are any characters in your string that contain either `Z` or `z` (or `Q` or `q`, depending on what you want).  `regexp` returns the indices of where these characters were found.  If there were `Z` or `z` (or `Q` or `q` characters, depending on what you want) characters found, then the indices would be non-empty, hence the `~isempty` check.  If there were no `Z` or `z` (or `Q` or `q`) characters that were found, this would be empty and so this statement is skipped.  What's important is that if we have found `Z`, `z` (or `Q`, `q`) characters, we immediately make `d` empty and **return** so that the rest of the logic is not run.

You can then carry on with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a character is in a string with: `any(d == 'Q') || any(d == 'Z')`